# Traversing into dates and getting the lowest day difference between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, web-applications

Hello its my first time to ask a question this year.
Please help me I'm begging you.

I have this reservation table that have startdate and enddate, now  I want to traverse to them and take note of their different intervals with my current date booking. After i get all the diffent interval, I would want to traverse also to that interval and get the or nearest day posible.

The nearest day would be `0(enddate == startdate)` because the check in time is fixed.

Assuming that there are a bunch of dates that have been booked in that the same room.

```
bookingstart = '2013-02-5 14:00:00' bookingend = '2013-02-7 14:00:00'
bookingstart = '2013-02-13 14:00:00' bookingend = '2013-02-16 14:00:00'
bookingstart = '2013-01-22 14:00:00' bookingend = '2013-02-23 14:00:00'
```

Now initial code goes like this:

```
$newbookingstart = '2013-01-24 14:00:00'
$newbookingend = '2013-01-27 14:00:00';

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT enddate, startdate FROM reservation WHERE rmlocation = 'RM24'");
if (!$sql) {
exit('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

$diffInterval = array();


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

if ($row['enddate'] >= $newbookingstart && $newbookingend <= $row['stardate']) {
    $diffInterval .= $row['startdate'] . $row['enddate'] . $row['rmlocation'];
}

}
//Get the $diffInterval, traverse and get the lowest date interval posible
```

My problems is how to get these codes right especially in getting the data in the db.
How to improve my search in the same room searching all the other enddates and startdates.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL DateTime field, it should be able the string you fetched from DB convert to something you can calculate with, e.g. strtotime and other date functions of PHP.

Other possibility is to calculate directly in SQL.

Comment: oh i forgot i know how to subtract the diff time using DateTime php function. But i have to make sure im getting the data right so im asking if how to traverse and get available room. How do you do that in mysql?

Comment: PHP currently only deliver strings from DB, the native functions can not understand MYSQL datatypes. As PHP is an dynamic, typeless language, more or less, this behavior is around in common places.

For MYSQL you can put the calculation in the WHERE clause of your statement. There are several functions to calculate dates (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html). Just transform your condition and you get back the needed result.